# How to use animation in Microsoft chart control?

Tags: c#, charts, controls, asp.net-3.5

I need to implement animation in Microsoft chart control like in [this link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/Demos/Blueprint/).

Is it possible to implement this?

If yes then how to implement?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Accoring to this

[Does this chart controller offers Animated charts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/0791639d-7c88-44da-b4c6-b3c0edeb5434)

> MS Chart Controls do not offer
>   animation.
>
> But you can animate the Charts by
>   using AJAX Update Panel to refresh
>   your data.

and

[chart animation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/MSWinWebChart/thread/afbf8e7c-756d-4841-8476-bdf1cb1baa75)

> Animations are not built into the MS
>   Chart product. ASP.NET chart is
>   rendered as image and you can only add
>   animations to the Windows Forms
>   control.

Comment: Is there any other way out to implement animation in MS Chart control?
Please help.